# Eagle custom part attributes

Tags: eaglecad, library

I'm creating a library part for a dual MOSFET driver IX442 which has 3 variants, IX4426, IX4427, IX4428.  The difference between the variants is in whether the outputs are inverted from the inputs.

Is there a way to set the pin name for pin 7 (OUTA or #OUTA depending on the variant) such that I can create a single schematic part for all variants and use an attribute to set the pin name accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Eagle doesn't have this level of parametrization.  [Neither do Altium, OrCAD.]

If you want to have distinct pin names** in distinct part numbers***, you'd have to make separate library parts.  Copy and paste will do the bulk of the work.

**  OUTA or #OUTA for pin 7
*** albeit they share the datasheet

P.S.  You can tell eagle to draw a proper overbar by using ! sign `!FOO!` produces \$\overline {FOO}\$

Answer (score 1):

I've confirmed that pin names cannot be dynamically set.

I've since worked around the issue for schematics through the following method:

- Set pin names to OUTA and OUTB and setting pin label visibility to off
- Create text fields next to each pin as >OUTA and >OUTB
- Create part attributes OUTA and OUTB with appropriate values for the labels
      for example  the IX4426 has both outputs inverted, so setting OUTA to !OUTA and OUTB to !OUTB will replace the values of >OUTA with !OUTA and >OUTB with !OUTB